# How to use pundit policy check within tabulatr2 data definition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pundit

I'm using [tabulatr2](https://github.com/metaminded/tabulatr2) to handle table alike data. However I can't wrap my head around how to include pundit's policy checks in tabulatr2's data definition.

So I have something akin to

```
class MystuffTabulatrData < Tabulatr::Data
  column :blah
  buttons do |b,r|
    if policy(r).destroy? # XXX: NoMethodError - undefined method `policy' for #<Data::Proxy:0x83f84bb0>
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

One usually uses something like `<%= table_for Mystuff %>` in a view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we work with Data::Proxy there, [the source suggests](https://github.com/metaminded/tabulatr2/blob/master/lib/tabulatr/data/proxy.rb#L32) that `@controller` should be available. So `@controller.policy(r)` works just fine.